# How can I exclude a light from being rendered but keep it's effects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

Well, its a bit more than that.

1. I created my scene, lets say a living room and did add a plane.
2. I did choose Emission as material for the plane. So it is my only light source for that scene. It makes nice light.
   Of course the plane shows up in the final render.

But I just want to use the light it creates but don´t want to see the plane it self in the final render in the scene.

Can that be done?

Thanks a lot
armin